# Where are the source files of Groovy's collection extensions located?

Tags: groovy

I am looking for how the methods like ArrayList#sort(Closure) are implemented in Groovy.  I've downloaded Groovy's source in a zip (http://groovy.codehaus.org/Building+Groovy+from+Source), but I can't find any file containing the source of extension methods to ArrayList.  Does anyone know where these Groovy extensions for Java's collection API are located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `sort` methods of `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods` class.